# Por qué mis mis links a otras páginas html no funcionan?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Estoy haciendo mi página web. Tengo un nav así.

```
<nav id="nav-main">
                        <ul>
                            <li>
                                <a href="#banner">Home</a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="#about">About</a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="#services">Things I can do</a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="#gallery">Portfolio</a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="#contact">Contact me</a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href=language/hola.html  class="external">ES</a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href=language/konnichi.html  class="external">JP</a>
                            </li>

                        </ul>


                    </nav>
```

todos mis anchor funcionan perfectamente. Lo que no funciona son los links a paginas html. He probado sin ese class external, con el target self y el blank para ver si funcionaba abriendome otro tab y no lo hace. Cuando pruebo links http://, me abre perfectamente descartando la opcion de que algo ocurra en el HTML. Tampoco tengo un elemento de alguna pagina JS que tenga propiedades como defaultPrevented, que también leí que podría hacerlo.
Lo que pasa cuando uno clickea en mi nav "ES" y "JP" es como que si lo haces desde abajo en la pagina (el menu tambien es sticky) se redirige como si fuera un anchor, al top de la página, lo cual no le veo sentido tampoco. 
Qué podría estar pasando?

Comment: No estas encerrando en comillas los link.
<a href="language/konnichi.html"  class="external">JP</a>

Comment: Mira [ask] <- ACA para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] <- ACA para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: Según el comentario del autor, "*si tenia un prevent default en el plugin para el sticky navbar*" ... Sin ver el código es imposible responder. Estoy votando por cerrar como que "no se puede reproducir".

Answer (score 4):

No estas encerrando en comillas los enlaces.

aqui no pones las comillas.

`<a href=language/hola.html  class="external">ES</a>`

deberia ser.

`<a href="language/konnichi.html" class="external">JP</a>`

Comment: Gracias por tu aporte, pero sigue funcionando igual aunque he puesto comillas..

Answer (score 0):

Tienes error de sintaxis. Como dice @Alcides Salazar no estas encerrando las comillas del atributo href.

Ejemplo : 
URL relativa: `<a href="language/konnichi.html">Link JP</a>`

Más Info en : [HTML  href Attribute](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_a_href.asp)

Comment: Gracias por tu aporte, pero sigue funcionando igual aunque he puesto comillas..

Comment: konnichi.html se encuentra en la carpeta language? si es así debe funcionar

Answer (score 0):

Sospecho que va por acá, primero prueba con `href="../language/konnichi.html"` y sí no funciona copia toda la ruta de tu html a tu editor y fíjate si haz especificado bien la ruta, y claro también mira los tools del navegador que uses, ahí te dirá que error tienes.

Comment: Ya encontre el error. Al final, si tenia un prevent default en el plugin para el sticky navbar. 
Lo que pasa es que si lo borro, mi sticky navbar ya no funciona y tampoco una animación de texto que tenia. 

Como puedo modificar esa línea para que no se rompa todo?!

Comment: A mi también me pasó eso, era un dolor de cabeza porque no sabía que pasaba con las re direcciones, lo peor que en la web si re direccionaba pero en celulares no, sólo quita el  "prevent default"  y va a seguir funcionando bien el plugin de stick, (si te sigue dando error pon otra pregunta para sacar el prevent sin alterar el funcionamiento del plugin)

Comment: Si!!! mil gracias! he sacado lo pequeñito del prevent default (bueno respetando la sintaxis) y me funciono! ese era el problemita solamente.Bien intrincado. Muchas gracias de nuevo!

Answer (score 0):

La sintaxis es importante pero debe de tener problemas con la ruta relativa, prueba esto si no estas utilizando :

```
<a href="./language/hola.html"  class="external">ES</a>
```

de lo contrario siempre generares rutas como esta: "/language/language/hola.html"

Saludos